# Android supports-screen is it resizeable or any density?

Tags: android, manifest, android-manifest

I have taken note of some recent (and not so recent) blog posts on developer.android.com and have been adding in things like uses-feature and supports-screen elements to my manifest.

The problem is I don't really under stand the resizeable and any density tags in supports-screen.

I am supplying HDPI (drawable-hdpi) images for a few items as needed, though the majority are using a default image in drawable.

How do I need to set the resizeable and density tags, as I am struggling to understand their intent from the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uh, well, that's like a chapter in a book, more than can reasonably fit in a StackOverflow answer.

Fortunately, I [serialized](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/16/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part/) [parts](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/18/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-2/) of [such](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/02/23/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-3/) a [chapter](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/01/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-4/) on [AndroidGuys](http://www.androidguys.com/2010/03/02/handling-multiple-screen-sizes-part-5/).

Comment: That will keep me busy for a few hours then, will have a read when I can and get back to this.  Looks like a very good chapter though.